# Ruby - Can I use classes from a gem that aren't defined in a module?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

As the question might indicate, I am still very new to Ruby.  I'm developing my first custom gem as my own tutorial.  In this case, it's a few classes for managing a deck of cards.  I've successfully built and installed the gem, but when I try to use it in IRB, I'm getting a 'uninitialized constant' error.  I'm using Ruby 2.0.  Here's the basic run-down:

In my gem I have three classes in `lib`: `Card.rb`, `Deck.rb`, and `card_deck.rb` (which was auto-generated.  `card_deck.rb` defines the module `CardDeck`, and the `Card` and `Deck files define classes named the same thing respectively.  After installing my gem, I run irb and get the following:

```
$> require 'card_deck'
=> true
$> CardDeck
=> CardDeck
```

This tells me the gem was installed successfully.  However, when I try using `Card` or `Deck` I get the following:

```
$> Card
NameError: uninitialized constant Card
```

So my question is: do any classes that I want to be available from my gem need to be included in a module, or do they need to be required or imported differently?  In my gemspec the lib folder is listed in the required_path property.  Does this mean that any class I want to be accessible after requiring my gem needs to be defined in a module?

Again, I've done a little Rails work, but am still new to Ruby as a whole and building gems.  Thanks for any input and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best things I've found to do in a case where you don't really know the proper way to do something: find a popular gem or library for your language, and note the way that it's structured. Do this for 4-5 gems and see what you notice, it'll have a two-fold effect for you. One, you'll have a better grasp of Ruby itself by just reading code, and two you'll pick up patterns and nuances of the language.

I would be say yes, in my admittedly naive amount of knowledge on Gems. I've tried the class << self bit but it stinks of code smell.

These might be of some help for gem creation:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/gem-creation-with-bundler/

The Ruby style guide will help acclimate you to some of the other nuances scattered about:
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  Since both my classes are fairly small I just included them in the same module.  Not ideal, but since the purpose of this was to learn how to work with and create gems, I'm content.  Thanks! :)